# Pie chart legend colours are not being updated mpandroidchart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

In MpAndroidChart while using pie chart .was successfully able to draw the pie chart.  when tried to add custom labels and colours to the legend of the chart.Label is getting updated but is getting a blue legend color for all legends.

```
   ArrayList<String> PieEntryLabels = new ArrayList<>();
    PieEntryLabels.add("January");
    PieEntryLabels.add("February");
    PieEntryLabels.add("March");
    PieEntryLabels.add("April");

    List<LegendEntry> legendEntries = new ArrayList<>();

    int[] colorList = new int[] { R.color.graphcolor1, R.color.graphcolor2,R.color.graphcolor3,R.color.graphcolor4};
    pieDataSet.setColors(colorList, context);
    for (int i = 0; i < PieEntryLabels.size(); i++) {
        LegendEntry entry = new LegendEntry();
        entry.formColor =colorList[i];
        entry.label = PieEntryLabels.get(i);
        legendEntries.add(entry);
    }

    pieChart.getLegend().setCustom(legendEntries);
```

[image]

Comment: can you share colors.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue while i added colorlist in below way

```
    int[] colorList =  new int[]{Color.parseColor("#C570C5"),
            Color.parseColor("#E0A2E0"),
            Color.parseColor("#DDBFDD"),
            Color.parseColor("#E7D7E7")};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing hex code of color accent or color primary to your required colors in colors.xml.